# Expo ejected app - Push via Firebase not working in iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, expo

Exported an Expo project to react native, all is well except the iOS remote push notifications via Firebase.

Steps:

1. Developed Expo managed project and built both platforms (all keys were generated by Expo)
2. Used expo-notifications.
3. Ejected.

Note - Push are working great locally (app can send push to itself on both platform) and Push via the Expo api is also working great.

My wish if for Firebase to be able to send push via the cloud messaging for both platforms (uploaded the p8 that was downloaded from the expo servers).

Comment: Popping it up again